# compiling openCV: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: compiling, make, opencv, source

I am currently following [those steps provided by servo](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=166601) to compile and setup openCV. However I am stuck just after having done this:

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON –D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON –D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_JPEG=ON -D WITH_JASPER=ON
```

When I now try to do "sudo make" just like described in the tutorial I get the following error: compiling openCV: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

**EDIT: ** I have tried [those steps](http://answers.opencv.org/question/89075/no-makefile-to-build-after-cmake/) as well. Those work perfectly fine if do exactly what is described there. But the issue is that -in my case- I need to provide some extra info when executing the cmake command. When I do so, I run in exactly the same problem again.

Comment: and what "extra info" are you providing, exactly? have you examined the `cmake` command output to see what component is causing the problem?

Comment: @steeldriver not sure I can paste all the output from CMake here, that is quite a lot... I haven't really seen anything suspicious. What extra info would you need?